# Android: Method in MainActivity works fine, running same method in MainActivity via BroadcastReceiver class gives null pointer

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

So I have this method in my `MainActivity` and it works fine normally.

```
public void DailyQuoteDatabaseAccess(){

SQLiteOpenHelper sqLiteOpenHelper = new SQLiteAssetHelper(this, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
SQLiteDatabase SqlDb = sqLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
String rawQuery = "SELECT * FROM dailyQuoteTable ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
Cursor cursor = SqlDb.rawQuery(rawQuery, null);
DailyQuoteCursorAdapter DQCursorAdapter = new DailyQuoteCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
this.mDailyQuoteListView.setAdapter(DQCursorAdapter);
}
```

However, when I try to run it from my `BroadcastReceiver` class, it is accessed but the app crashes and I get the following error in **log cat**:

```
Process: com.myapps.dailyquotes, PID: 15024
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } in com.myapps.dailyquotes.TodaysQuoteAlarmReceiver@d63089d
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_52497(LoadedApk.java:1323)
at android.app.-$Lambda$aS31cHIhRx41653CMnd4gZqshIQ.$m$7(Unknown Source:4)
at android.app.-$Lambda$aS31cHIhRx41653CMnd4gZqshIQ.run(Unknown Source:39)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:152)
at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.<init>(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:109)
at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.<init>(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:129)
at com.myapps.dailyquotes.MainActivity.DailyQuoteDatabaseAccess(MainActivity.java:403)
```

**This is my `BroadcastReceiver` class:**

```
package com.myapps.dailyquotes;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class TodaysQuoteAlarmReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
mainActivity.DailyQuoteDatabaseAccess();

}
}
```

The line it highlights in the `DailyQuoteDatabaseAccess` method in the `MainActivity` is this one:

```
SQLiteOpenHelper sqLiteOpenHelper = new SQLiteAssetHelper(this, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
```

I call this from MainActivity onCreate... it links to the TodaysQuoteAlarmReceiver:

```
 public void AlarmForQuote() {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 28);

    Calendar cur = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (cur.after(calendar)) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    mTodaysQuoteIntent = new Intent(this, 
 TodaysQuoteAlarmReceiver.class);
    int ALARM_ID = 10000;
    mTodaysQuotePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), ALARM_ID, mTodaysQuoteIntent, 
 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mNewTodaysQuote = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    mNewTodaysQuote.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, mTodaysQuotePendingIntent);

}
```

Comment: `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();`? This is a Disaster .

Comment: I found that out. Any suggestions how to make what I need to happen happen?

Comment: What is the action of TodaysQuoteAlarmReceiver?? Mention it .

Comment: Thank you. Good point. The action is to call the DailyQuoteDatabaseAccess method that is inside of the MainActivity. That method will populate a listview with a new quote each morning at 900am. That is what I am trying to accomplish anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activity classes in Android are never created with the new operator. They are created by the system when fulfilling an intent.  If you create an activity the way you are doing so, it will not have the proper context set. That's why when it goes to create the SQLiteAssetHelper, you get a null pointer.

Comment: Greg, thank you for that information. Do you have an idea how to do what I did properly?

Comment: Keeping in mind that I do not want to start MainActivity over each time the alarm is fired. I just need it to populate a new daily quote.

Comment: Then you probably want to register the receiver as an inner class inside your MainActivity, rather than a separate class.  By making it an inner class inside your activity, you can simply invoke DailyQuoteDatabaseAccess() and you don't need a reference to a MainActivity object because you're already in the class.

Comment: Thank you Greg. I am going to try that.

Comment: public class TodaysQuoteReceiverInnerStaticClass extends 
    BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent){
        MainActivity.this.DailyQuoteDatabaseAccess();
        }

    }

Comment: Does that appear correct? I am using that in the MainActivity and it's not firing the alarm anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you calling registerReceiver() in your MainActivity onCreate()? You should also call unregisterReceiver() in onDestroy().

Comment: I adapted the code to what's in these comments. Runs the correct method now, DailyQuoteDatabaseAccess and populates the list view. However, it is re-populating the listview every single time the activity is re-created. For example, if I navigate to another activity then back the MainActivity, it populates the listview again as if the alarm fired again. It doesn't persist. However, the data does not change at the time specified in the AlarmForQuote method. I need it to fire when app is first installed and not change the data in the listview until the next alarm time even when app is closed.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to accomplish but it sounds like you need to separate list view display logic from your daily quote logic. You have an alarm going off that updates a list view with fresh information from your database. But if the app is not running, there's no point in refreshing the list. Unless you want the app to open itself every day at 9:00am?

Comment: Thanks Greg. I upvoted this answer because you solved one of the problems I was having which covers the question I asked in this thread. Now to get it to actually recognize the alarm parameters and not reset each time i leave and come back to the activity.